# Tutorial in datamining

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence

Where can I find about tutorial of datamining in SQL server 2012 or 2008 R2?

The purpose is to improve my knowledge in datamining.

Comment: You really should try very hard to start asking more specific questions.  As written a valid answer would be `Yes`, and you are asking for extremely general information about a very broad topic.

Answer (score 2):

this book is useful

[http://www.amazon.com/Data-Mining-Microsoft-Server-2008/dp/0470277742/ref=pd_sim_b_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470277742)

and here is some reviews and nice articles about it

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jamiemac/data-mining-with-sql-server-2008)

http://richardlees.blogspot.com/2008/12/book-review-data-mining-with-sql-server.html

slideshow
http://www.slideshare.net/PeterGfader/10-data-mining

--

i also suggest watching these video tutorials by Learn it first
as a start they can give you a basic but useful introduction

Data Mining with Analysis Services
http://www.learnitfirst.com/Course/165/Chapter/292/Data-Mining-SSAS.aspx

http://www.learnitfirst.com/Course/165/SSAS-2008.aspx

--

chapter 11 of BI Architecture and Design Guide (best practices)
is focused on Data mining

http://biarchanddesignguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/6572

Comment: I wrote a whole series of tutorials called A Rickety Stairway to SQL Server Data Mining at https://multidimensionalmayhem.wordpress.com/category/a-rickety-stairway-to-sql-server-data-mining/ while trying to educate myself about it. I didn't know what I was doing half the time, but it's still useful in pointing out a lot of "gotchas."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief tutorial: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167167.aspx